# Handle localization in single-page web application

Tags: javascript, node.js, single-page-application, i18next

I have to add a localization mechanism into an existing Node.js web application.
The application is composed of:

- Node.js server
- Dojo / javascript single web page (i.e. each `dojox/mobile/View` is shown as needed)

I've already configured [i18nextify](https://github.com/i18next/i18nextify) and it works fine, adding a query parameter to the initial request:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/?lng=en

My question is related about how to handle this query *after* the page has loaded.
Here the flow of the application:

1. the users load the initial page with the default url (i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8000)
2. after logging in, the server retrieves the pre-defined language for that user (the application should not offer the language selection to the end user)
3. now the new views show the desired language

A way I found:

- After the client receives the language tag ('en') in the login answer - see below, it stores it in the session storage and reloads the page appending the language to the query request ('/?lng=en'). On next reload, if the application finds the existence of that variable in the session storage pass-over the login page. The logout function will remove the variable.

*I'm afraid about security issue here*, or out-of-sync between session storage variables and server knowledge of client's connection.

Here my code for initializing i18next on the server:

```
app.js
var express = require('express');
var i18next = require('i18next');
var FsBackend = require('i18next-node-fs-backend');
var middleware = require('i18next-express-middleware');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var https = require('https');
var routes = require('./routes/index');

i18next
  .use(FsBackend)
  .init({
    lng: 'it',
    saveMissing: true,
    debug: true,
    backend: {
      loadPath: __dirname + '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
      addPath: __dirname + '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.missing.json'
    },
    preload: [ 'it' ],
    nsSeparator: '#||#',
    keySeparator: '#|#'
  });

var app = express();

app.use(middleware.handle(i18next, {
}));

app.use('/locales', express.static('locales'));
app.post('/locales/add/:lng/:ns', middleware.missingKeyHandler(i18next));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', { message: err.message, error: err });
    });
}

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', { message: err.message, error: {} });
});

module.exports = app;
```

index.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');

router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("index", {title: "Smart Data Collector"});
});

router.get('/i18nextify.min.js', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../node_modules/i18nextify/i18nextify.js', 'utf-8', function(err, doc) {
    res.send(doc);
  });
});

router.post("/api/login", function (req, res, next) {
    var header = JSON.parse(req.headers.login);
    var name = header.name;
    var pin = header.pin;

  // myengine is a collection of utility functions
  myengine.login(name, pin, function (result, sid) {
        res.status(200).json({
            result: result.login,
            sid: sid,
            name: name,
            id: result.id,
            lang: result.lang // here the language retrieved by the server
        });
    });
});
```

and here the client initialization:

```
script(src="/i18nextify.min.js")
script(src="/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js")
script(type="text/javascript").

    var translation = window.i18nextify.init({
      debug: true,
      saveMissing: true,
      namespace: 'translation',
      ns: ['common', 'commonNested'],
      ignoreTags: ['SCRIPT', 'h6'],
      ignoreIds: ['ignoreMeId'],
      ignoreClasses: ['ignoreMeClass']
    });

    ...other js libraries follows
```

Comment: via window.i18nextify.i18next you get full access to the below i18next instance to use any API call on that...beside that the xhr-backend is included and could be configured at will https://github.com/i18next/i18next-xhr-backend

Comment: means you could use https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware#language-detection and sync lng from server to client using the cookie

Comment: Thanks for your hint. If you want to elaborate it a bit and write an answer  I'll accept it.